# Simple restaurant menu

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, html, css

As stated in the title, the code produces a simple drop-down menu that allows you to select your `Starter`, `Main` and `Dessert` courses, and will show your order in a small box underneath (like a bill).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Variables
  var selectedStarter = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var selectedMain = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var selectedDessert = {
    dish: "(None)",
    price: 0
  };
  var starter = {
    firstDish: "Salad",
    firstDishPrice: 15,
    secondDish: "Soup",
    secondDishPrice: 7,
    thirdDish: "Fish rolls",
    thirdDishPrice: 12
  };

  var main = {
    firstDish: "Steak",
    firstDishPrice: 17,
    secondDish: "Salmon",
    secondDishPrice: 12,
    thirdDish: "Rissotto",
    thirdDishPrice: 9
  };

  var dessert = {
    firstDish: "Sorbet",
    firstDishPrice: 4,
    secondDish: "Fruit salad",
    secondDishPrice: 6,
    thirdDish: "Apple pie",
    thirdDishPrice: 5
  };

  function total() {
    return selectedStarter.price + selectedMain.price + selectedDessert.price;
  }

  function selectedStarterFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedStarter.price = price;
    selectedStarter.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  function selectedMainFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedMain.price = price;
    selectedMain.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  function selectedDessertFnc(dish, price) {
    selectedDessert.price = price;
    selectedDessert.dish = dish;
    $("#total").html(total());
    return dish + "(" + price + ")";
  }

  // Instantiating HTML Button Elements
  // Starter Elements
  document.getElementById("btStarter1").value =
    starter.firstDish + ": " + starter.firstDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btStarter2").value =
    starter.secondDish + ": " + starter.secondDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btStarter3").value =
    starter.thirdDish + ": " + starter.thirdDishPrice;

  // Main Elements
  document.getElementById("btMain1").value =
    main.firstDish + ": " + main.firstDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btMain2").value =
    main.secondDish + ": " + main.secondDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btMain3").value =
    main.thirdDish + ": " + main.thirdDishPrice;

  // Dessert Elements
  document.getElementById("btDessert1").value =
    dessert.firstDish + ": " + dessert.firstDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btDessert2").value =
    dessert.secondDish + ": " + dessert.secondDishPrice;

  document.getElementById("btDessert3").value =
    dessert.thirdDish + ": " + dessert.thirdDishPrice;

  // Your Order: Elements
  document.getElementById("selectedStarter").innerHTML =
    selectedStarter.dish + " (" + selectedStarter.price + ")";

  document.getElementById("selectedMain").innerHTML =
    selectedMain.dish + " (" + selectedMain.price + ")";

  document.getElementById("selectedDessert").innerHTML =
    selectedDessert.dish + " (" + selectedDessert.price + ")";

  // Functions (JQuery)
  // Main menu onClicks handler
  $("#btMenu").click(function() {
    $("#liMainMenu").toggle("slow");
  });

  $("#btStarter").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btStarter").css("background-color", "black");
      } else {
        $("#btStarter").css("background-color", "blue");
      }
    });
  });

  $("#btMain").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btMain").css("background-color", "black");
      } else {
        $("#btMain").css("background-color", "blue");
      }
    });
  });

  $("#btDessert").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $("#btDessert").css("background-color", "black");
      } else {
        $("#btDessert").css("background-color", "blue");
      }
    });
  });

  // Starter onClicks
  $("#btStarter1").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedStarter").html(selectedStarterFnc(starter.firstDish, starter.firstDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btStarter2").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedStarter").html(selectedStarterFnc(starter.secondDish, starter.secondDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btStarter3").click(function() {
    $("#liStarter").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedStarter").html(selectedStarterFnc(starter.thirdDish, starter.thirdDishPrice));
  });

  // Main onClicks
  $("#btMain1").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedMain").html(selectedMainFnc(main.firstDish, main.firstDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btMain2").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedMain").html(selectedMainFnc(main.secondDish, main.secondDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btMain3").click(function() {
    $("#liMain").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedMain").html(selectedMainFnc(main.thirdDish, main.thirdDishPrice));
  });

  // Dessert onClicks
  $("#btDessert1").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedDessert").html(selectedDessertFnc(dessert.firstDish, dessert.firstDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btDessert2").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedDessert").html(selectedDessertFnc(dessert.secondDish, dessert.secondDishPrice));
  });

  $("#btDessert3").click(function() {
    $("#liDessert").children("li").children("input").css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $("#selectedDessert").html(selectedDessertFnc(dessert.thirdDish, dessert.thirdDishPrice));
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  background: #353535;
  outline: solid 2px #353535;
  border: solid 2px white;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.ul {
  display: none;
}
.table {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  width: 33%;
}
.table th {
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 30px;
}
.table tr,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Restaurant Menu With JQuery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" class="button" id="btMenu" value="Menu">
  <ul id="liMainMenu" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter" value="Starter">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain" value="Main">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert" value="Dessert">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liStarter" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btStarter3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liMain" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btMain3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="liDessert" class="ul">
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert2" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" class="button" id="btDessert3" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <table class="table">
    <th>Your Order:</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Starter :</td>
      <td id="selectedStarter"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Main :</td>
      <td id="selectedMain"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dessert :</td>
      <td id="selectedDessert"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Total :</td>
      <td id="total"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Now this question could use a better description of what the code does, and possibly be inserted into a [StackSnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  Do that and you've earned my upvote!

Comment: will do, and the StackSnippet is amazing, first time I see that tool. regarding the description, well the title say it all tbh but ill try. appreciate the guidance.

Comment: You're already including jquery, so why not also use it for your button: `$("#btStarter1").val( ... );`

Comment: And for innerHTML, you can use `$().html( ... )`

Comment: well that was exactly my thoughts just not sure about certain things such as the function I made, should they change the button themselves or return the value? what the correct simpler way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first warn you that you have fallen into a classic anti-pattern.  When you see yourself tempted to write code that starts naming variables/objects/item with names like `btStarter*` (with `*` being numbers), usually this means you should be thinking of these things as an array.

Also you have a lot of repetitive code that you can refactor out.

You need to begin to come to terms that jQuery is especially powerful at dealing with collections of DOM elements.  So again, when you begin doing things like make element ID's like `btStarter*` this probably means you should be dealing with the collections of buttons logically using the same class.

Finally, you really haven't embraced an "object oriented" paradigm at all, which is something that could really help organize your code.  I will show you an alternate implementation that you might find helps prompt some different thinking.

This may seem like a lot of code, but you might find this sort of approach helpful over the long term with regards to being able to more easily maintain and reuse this code.

The approach:

- Put your logic into classes and import via include file that you load in document header. This also enables this logic to be transportable.  You need to create another menu page?  Just include this file.

Example:

```
  // build Dish class
  function Dish(name, price) {
      // not shown - you should validate proper data types and values
      // for name(string) and price(int or float, positive value, etc.)
      this.name = name;
      this.price = price;
      // in future you might add other properties here (ingredients, picture URL's, etc.)
  }

  // add methods to the Dish prototype to expose dish behavior
  Dish.prototype = {
      // not currently used
  };

  // build Menu class to store menu information
  function Menu() {
      this.categories = [];
      this.menuTree = {};
  }

  // add methods to the Menu prototype to expose menu behavior
  Menu.prototype = {
      addCategory: function addCategory(category) {
          // not shown - you should validate proper data type
          // for category(string)
          // add category to menu tree
          this.menuTree[category] = [];
          // add category to list of categories on Menu
          this.categories.push(category);
          // return the object for method chaining
          return this;          
      },
      addDish: function addDish(dish, category) {
          if(dish instaceof Dish === false) {
              console.log('Need to pass a Dish object.');
              return null;
          }

          // if category was not passed, use last category added
          if(category === undefined) {
              var lastCatArray = this.categories.slice(-1);
              category = lastCatArray[0];
          }
          this.menuTree[category].push(dish);
          return this;
      }
  }

  // build object to define an orderable Meal
  // we will later use this class when rendering the menu selection
  // this simple example assumes that the meas consists of one item from
  // each menu category
  function Meal(menu) {
     // not shown - validate valid menu object is passed
     // set menu object in this class
     this.menu = menu;
     // object to store current menu selections
     this.menuSelections = {};
     // build out "slots" to hold menu selections
     this.menu.categories.forEach(function (value, index) {
         this.menuSelections[value] = null;    
     });
  }

  // add methods to Meal
  Meal.prototype = {
      selectCourseOption: function(course, dish) {
          // not shown - validate course and dish parameters
          this.menuSelections[course] = dish;
          return this;   
      },
      getMealCost: function() {
          var totalCost = 0;
          for (course in this.menuSelections) {
              totalCost += this.menuSelections[course].price;
          }
          return totalCost;
      }
  }

  // create class to render HTML view necessary for meal selection
  function MealSelectionHTMLFactory(meal, config) {
      // not shown - validate valid Meal object passed
      this.meal = meal;
      // extend/override default config if if anything passed
      // not currently used
      this.config = $.extend(this.config, config);
  }

  MealSelectionHTMLFactory.prototype = {
      // store some base config for rendering
      // we apply this at prototype level,
      // as we want to apply to all instances of this class
      this.config = {
          // Not used currently. It could be good idea to put things
          // such as default DOM element id and class names into this
          // config such that they are not hard coded into the jQuery
          // DOM element generation code in this class.
      },
      renderMenuDOM(targetSelector) {
          // local variable to use as handle to menu tree
          var menuTree = this.meal.menu.menuTree;        

          // start building elements for DOM inserting
          // you may ultimately weant to consider some sort of
          // templating engine, rather than building DOM elements this way

          // create wrapper div to contain this whole thing 
          var $menuDOM = $('div');
          // main button
          $menuDOM.append(
              '<input type="button" class="button" id="btMenu" value="Menu">'
          );
          // start with menu shell
          $menuDOM.append(
              '<ul id="liMainMenu" class="ul">'
          );
          // get handle for main menu
          $mainMenu = $menuDom.find('#liMainMenu');

          // create shell for order table
          var $orderTable = $(
              '<table id="orderTable" class="table">'
          );
          $orderTable.append('<th>Your Order:</th>');


          // iterate through courses updating navigation, selection form
          // and order summary table
          for (course in this.menuSelections) {
              // update main menu
              $mainMenu.append(
                  '<li>' + 
                  '<input type="button" class="button courseToggle" value="' +
                  course + '"></li>'
              );

              // add course menu
              // note that I am applying courseMenu class to this item
              var $courseMenu = $(
                  '<ul class="ul courseMenu ' + course + '">'
              );

              // iterate dish options for this course adding them to menu
              for (var i = 0; i < menuTree[course].length; i++)) {
                  var localDish = menuTree[course][i];
                  // note we capture current course and index position of dish
                  // into data-* properties
                  var $dish = $.(
                      '<li>' + 
                      '<input type="button" class="button dishToggle" value="' +
                      localDish.name + '" data-course=" + course + '" ' + 
                      data-index="' + i + '"></li>'
                  );
                  $courseMenu.append($dish);
              }

              // add this course menu to menu DOM 
              $menuDOM.append($courseMenu);

              // update order table
              var $tableRow = $.('<tr class="orderTableRow ' + course + '">');
              $tableRow.append('<td>' + course + ' :</td>');
              $tableRow.append('<td class="selectedDish">');
              $orderTable.append($tableRow);   
          }

          // add total area to order table
          $orderTable.append(
              '<tr><td>Total :</td><td id="mealTotal">0</td>'
          );

          // now add elements to DOM at target selector
          $(targetSelector).append($menuDom);
          $(targetSelector).append($orderTable);
      },
      addEventHandlers: function () {
          // local variable for access meal
          var mealLocal = this.meal;
          // local variable to use as handle to menu tree
          var menuTree = mealLocal.menu.menuTree;

          // main button behavior toggle
          $("#btMenu").click(function() {
              // togle button class
              $(this).toggleClass('active');
              // show/hide menu
              $("#liMainMenu").toggle("slow");
          });

          // course menu toggles
          $('.courseToggle').click(function() {
             var clickedCourse = $(this).attr("value");
             // change button class
             $(this).toggleClass('active');
             // show/hide menu
             $('.courseMenu.' + clickedCourse).toggle('slow');
          });

          // dish selection toggles
          $('.dishToggle').click(function() {
              // get jQuery collection for all dishes of this same course
              var $allDishesForCourse = $(this)
                  .closest('.courseMenu')
                  .find('.dishToggle');
              // toggle all dishes into notSelected state
              $allDishesForCourse.addClass('notSelected');

              // put selected class in selected state
              $(this).removeClass('notSelected');
              $(this).addClass('selected');

              // update meal object to reflected selected item
              // first get data from clicked element so we can locate
              // the dish object in menu tree
              var selectedDishCourse = $(this).data('course');
              var selectedDishIndex = parseInt($(this).data('index'));

              // get dish object
              var selectedDish = menuTree[selectedDishCourse][selectedDishIndex];

              // set dish object to meal
              mealLocal.selectCourseOption(selectedDishCourse, selectedDish);

              // now update the order table
              // first course selection
              $('.orderTableRow.' + selectedDishCourse + ' .selectedDish)
                  .html(selectedDish.name);
              // thence total price
              $('#mealTotal').html(mealLocal.getMealCost());
          });          
      },
      renderMenu: function(targetSelector) {
          this.renderMenuDOM(targetSelector);
          this.addEventHandlers();
      }        
  }
```

- Now, you can REALLY simplify your code in the document.ready handler. This code should only contain the specific configuration and execution information for this specific menu page.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // build your actual menu
  var menu = new Menu();
  menu.addCategory('Starter')
      .addDish(new Dish('Salad', 15))
      // repeat for other dishes in this category
      .addDish(...);
  menu.addCategory('Main')
      // add dishes to this category as shown above 
      .addDish(...);      
  menu.addCategory('Dessert')
      // add dishes to this category as shown above 
      .addDish(...);

  // create Meal instance
  var meal = new Meal(menu);

  // render menu view
  var factory = MealSelectionHTMLFactory(meal);
  factory.renderMenu('body');
}
```

- You also simplify your HTML source code, as the classes now perform all the HTML DOM element creation necessary to build the meal selector. All you need to do is tell the MealSelectionHTMLFactory what DOM element to insert the menu into and it does its thing.  You have "componetized" the meal selection menu such that it can be reused anywhere.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Restaurant Menu With JQuery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://yourdomain/path/to/jsincludes.js"></script>
</head>

<body></body>
```